# Rescue a damaged SD card

Tags: usb, mount, filesystem

My SD card died, but I have some photos on it which I would love to rescue.

`dosfsck  -w -r -l -a -v -t /dev/sda1`

returns the following:

```
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
Checking we can access the last sector of the filesystem
Boot sector contents:
System ID "        "
Media byte 0xf8 (hard disk)
       512 bytes per logical sector
     32768 bytes per cluster
      1124 reserved sectors
First FAT starts at byte 575488 (sector 1124)
         2 FATs, 32 bit entries
   3906560 bytes per FAT (= 7630 sectors)
Root directory start at cluster 2 (arbitrary size)
Data area starts at byte 8388608 (sector 16384)
    976512 data clusters (31998345216 bytes)
63 sectors/track, 255 heads
      8192 hidden sectors
  62513152 sectors total
Both FATs appear to be corrupt. Giving up.
```

However, I did manage to copy the card using `dd if=/dev/sda1 of=backup.card`. Is there a way I can now use this file to restore my photographs?

Mounting it doesn't work:

```
# mount -t vfat backup.card  /mnt
mount: /mnt: can't read superblock on /dev/loop2.
```

I have read [an interesting description](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8366) on how to graft a part of a damaged system onto another one, however I was not able to do anything with this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) is the usual answer. It doesn't try to mount the filesystem, it just scans for structured files in a block device.

Comment: This is a nice answer. In the meanwhile, I found another solution: `fatcat`.